# How to parse out lists returned by an API into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

I am requesting a data loop, I want to get the *id* of a bunch of coins, to run an indicator through them to detect which one is trending and filter the rest out.

```
API_URL = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3'

r_coins_d = requests.get(API_URL + '/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false')
d_coins = r_coins_d.json()
df_coins_markets = pd.DataFrame(d_coins)

#=========== GET COIN IDS =======
for n in range(10):
    coin_id = df_coins_markets.id[n]
    r_market_d = requests.get(API_URL + f'/coins/{coin_id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=hourly')
    d_market = r_market_d.json()
    df_market = pd.DataFrame(d_market)
    df_market.columns = ['date', 'price', 'haha']
    #df_market['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_market['date'], unit='ms')
    print(d_market)
```

However, the following code returns an error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How to progress?

EDIT: FULL ERROR MESSAGE:

```
le "debug.py", line 24, in <module>
    df_market['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_market['date'], unit='ms')
  File "/Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 801, in to_datetime
    cache_array = _maybe_cache(arg, format, cache, convert_listlike)
  File "/Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 173, in _maybe_cache
    if not should_cache(arg):
  File "/Users/teo/.local/share/virtualenvs/trendingcoin-nriNAUCq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 137, in should_cache
    unique_elements = set(islice(arg, check_count))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

UPDATE: after following the advice of Trenton, It works if I keep the input as `df_market = pd.DataFrame(d_market['prices'], columns=['dateTime', 'price'])`

however if I add another column I would like to have

`df_market = pd.DataFrame(d_market[['prices', 'total_volumes']], columns=['dateTime', 'price'])`
again I get the error that the TypeError: Unhashable Type: list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First Section

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make the API call
API_URL = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3'

r_coins_d = requests.get(API_URL + '/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false')
d_coins = r_coins_d.json()

# create the markets dataframe
df_coins_markets = pd.DataFrame(d_coins)

# display(df_coins_markets.head())
         id symbol      name                                                                           image  current_price    market_cap  market_cap_rank  fully_diluted_valuation  total_volume  high_24h       low_24h  price_change_24h  price_change_percentage_24h  market_cap_change_24h  market_cap_change_percentage_24h  circulating_supply  total_supply  max_supply       ath  ath_change_percentage                  ath_date        atl  atl_change_percentage                  atl_date                                                                               roi              last_updated
0   bitcoin    btc   Bitcoin        https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/1/large/bitcoin.png?1547033579       37958.00  704703722512                1             7.947549e+11   47467298406  38237.00  36673.000000        723.720000                      1.94367           1.168963e+10                           1.68678        1.862056e+07  2.100000e+07  21000000.0  41940.00               -9.76302  2021-01-08T15:05:37.863Z  67.810000            55711.87093  2013-07-06T00:00:00.000Z                                                                              None  2021-02-05T23:14:54.266Z
1  ethereum    eth  Ethereum     https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/279/large/ethereum.png?1595348880        1713.19  195808148792                2                      NaN   38923140914   1752.05   1587.800000         92.100000                      5.68139           9.863290e+09                           5.30442        1.145515e+08           NaN         NaN   1752.05               -2.72207  2021-02-05T16:15:12.089Z   0.432979           393534.55297  2015-10-20T00:00:00.000Z  {'times': 59.35104667718437, 'currency': 'btc', 'percentage': 5935.104667718438}  2021-02-05T23:13:13.252Z
2    tether   usdt    Tether  https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/325/large/Tether-logo.png?1598003707           1.00   27851925281                3                      NaN   88244095697      1.00      0.994689          0.005368                      0.53863           1.790294e+07                           0.06432        2.779522e+10  2.779522e+10         NaN      1.32              -24.36226  2018-07-24T00:00:00.000Z   0.572521               74.79873  2015-03-02T00:00:00.000Z                                                                              None  2021-02-05T23:10:05.466Z
```

---

### Second Section

- If `df_market = pd.DataFrame(d_market)` is used, columns of `lists` are created.

```py
                                prices                         market_caps                        total_volumes
0  [1609978421091, 10.051749696667137]  [1609978421091, 9599471028.799435]  [1609978421091, 1433598906.2376666]
1  [1609981399992, 10.404913579249927]  [1609981399992, 9800416299.991219]   [1609981399992, 1484399005.370463]
```

- Each list contains a `'date'` and associated value for `'price'`, `'market_caps'`, and `'total_volumes'`, respectively.
- The loop has been updated to correctly extract the information from the `lists` into separate dataframes, and then combines the dataframes with `pandas.concat`

```py
df_market_dict = dict()  # create a dict of dataframes

# iterate through the unique coin market ids
for coin_id in df_coins_markets.id.unique()[:5]:  # first 5
    print(f'Coin ID: {coin_id}')

    # call the API
    r_market_d = requests.get(API_URL + f'/coins/{coin_id}/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=30&interval=hourly')

    # extract the JSON from the response
    d_market = r_market_d.json()
    
    # separately extract each key from the json
    prices = pd.DataFrame(d_market['prices'], columns=['date', 'prices']).set_index('date')
    market_caps = pd.DataFrame(d_market['market_caps'], columns=['date', 'market_caps']).set_index('date')
    total_volumes = pd.DataFrame(d_market['total_volumes'], columns=['date', 'total_volumes']).set_index('date')

    # combine the separate dataframes
    df_market = pd.concat([prices, market_caps, total_volumes], axis=1)
    
    # convert the index to a datetime dtype
    df_market.index = pd.to_datetime(df_market.index, unit='ms')
    
    # add the market_data dataframe to the dict, with the coin_id as the key
    df_market_dict[coin_id] = df_market  
    
    display(df_market.head())  # use print if not in a notebook or spyder
```

- Display a dataframe from `df_market_dict`

```py
df_market_dict['bitcoin'].head()

                               prices   market_caps  total_volumes
date                                                              
2021-01-07 01:05:05.955  37215.781816  6.929761e+11   7.262550e+10
2021-01-07 02:08:34.785  36981.672166  6.871691e+11   7.031503e+10
2021-01-07 03:02:56.008  37059.042450  6.890434e+11   7.341887e+10
2021-01-07 04:14:05.845  37493.615768  6.971249e+11   7.513032e+10
2021-01-07 05:21:11.600  37473.956686  6.967610e+11   6.715542e+10
```

### Plot the `DataFrames` from the `dict`

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 7))
for k, v in df_market_dict.items():
    v.plot(y='prices', label=f'{k}', ax=ax)

ax.set_title('Prices')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.legend(title='Coin ID', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat()` to pull together all the results of detailed request.  There are >1.5k columns after `pd.json_normalize()` out put is just a sample

```
import requests
API_URL = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3'

r_coins_d = requests.get(API_URL + '/coins/markets', params={"vs_currency":"usd"})
d_coins = r_coins_d.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(d_coins)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for id in df.loc[:10,"id"].values:
    df2 = pd.concat([df2, pd.json_normalize(requests.get(f"{API_URL}/coins/{id}").json())])


df2s = df2.loc[:,[c for c in df2.columns if "." not in c or ".usd" in c or ".en" in c]]

print(df2s.iloc[:,:10].to_markdown())
```

### output

|  | id | symbol | name | asset_platform_id | block_time_in_minutes | hashing_algorithm | categories | public_notice | additional_notices | country_origin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bitcoin | btc | Bitcoin |  | 10 | SHA-256 | ['Cryptocurrency'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | ethereum | eth | Ethereum |  | 0 | Ethash | ['Smart Contract Platform'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | tether | usdt | Tether | ethereum | 0 |  | ['Stablecoins', 'USD Stablecoin'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | polkadot | dot | Polkadot |  | 0 |  | ['DOT Ecosystem'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | ripple | xrp | XRP |  | 0 |  | ['Cryptocurrency'] | SEC has charged Ripple with unregistered securities offering - https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2020-338 | [] |  |
| 0 | cardano | ada | Cardano |  | 0 |  | ['Smart Contract Platform'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | chainlink | link | Chainlink | ethereum | 0 |  | ['Business Services', 'Smart Contract Platform', 'DOT Ecosystem', 'Decentralized Finance (DeFi)', 'Oracle'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | litecoin | ltc | Litecoin |  | 2 | Scrypt | ['Cryptocurrency'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | binancecoin | bnb | Binance Coin | binancecoin | 0 |  | ['Exchange-based Tokens'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | bitcoin-cash | bch | Bitcoin Cash |  | 0 | SHA-256 | ['Cryptocurrency'] |  | [] |  |
| 0 | stellar | xlm | Stellar |  | 0 |  | ['Cryptocurrency', 'Smart Contract Platform'] |  | [] |  |