# How can I sort timestamp from following data dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
c=CoinGeckoAPI()
bdata=c.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id='bitcoin',vs_currency='usd',days=30)
data_=pd.DataFrame(bdata)
print(data_)
data=pd.to_datetime(data_[prices],unit='ms')
print(data)
```

**Output:**
[image: output I get!]

**Requirement:**
But I required output in which 4 columns:
Timestamp, Prices, Market_caps, Total_volume
And I want to change the timestamp format into to_datetime
In the above codes, I just sort the bitcoin data from pycoingecko

**Example:**
[image: output like this.]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse out lists returned by an API into a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66071243/how-to-parse-out-lists-returned-by-an-api-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this into a dataframe format like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
c=CoinGeckoAPI()
bdata=c.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id='bitcoin',vs_currency='usd',days=30)
prices = pd.DataFrame(bdata['prices'], columns=['TimeStamp', 'Price']).set_index('TimeStamp')
market_caps = pd.DataFrame(bdata['market_caps'], columns=['TimeStamp', 'Market Cap']).set_index('TimeStamp')
total_volumes = pd.DataFrame(bdata['total_volumes'], columns=['TimeStamp', 'Total Volumes']).set_index('TimeStamp')

# combine the separate dataframes
df_market = pd.concat([prices, market_caps, total_volumes], axis=1)

# convert the index to a datetime dtype
df_market.index = pd.to_datetime(df_market.index, unit='ms')
```

Code adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66071654/530160).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the timestamp column and convert it into date as following with minimum change to your code, you can follow up by merging the new column to your array:

```
import pandas as pd
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
c=CoinGeckoAPI()
bdata=c.get_coin_market_chart_by_id(id='bitcoin',vs_currency='usd',days=30)
data_=pd.DataFrame(bdata)
print(data_)
#data=pd.to_datetime(data_["prices"],unit='ms')
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in data_["prices"]])

df.columns = ["timestamp","data"]
df=pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"],unit='ms')
print(df)
```